# Criar vetor de forma automática em Python

Tags: array, lista, python-2.7

Sou novato em Python e preciso da ajuda com o seguinte:

- Tenho uma variável (x) que recebe um valor inteiro.
- Desejo que essa variável seja utilizada para criar um vetor com 1 linha e (x) colunas.
- Esse vetor deve possuir valores aleatórios e inteiros de 0 à 100.

Exemplo:

Para `x = 4`

Minha saída deve ser:

> `[50,40,60,70]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes usar o [modulo random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) para gerar os valores aleatórios:

Caso não queiras valores repetidos:

```
import random

x = 5
saida = []
for _ in range(x):
    saida.append(random.choice(range(100)))
print saida # [5, 75, 9, 38, 33]
```

Ou melhor ainda:

```
import random

x = 5
saida = random.sample(range(100),  x)
print(saida) # [69, 47, 43, 64, 16]
```

Se puderem existir valores repetidos:

```
import random

x = 5
saida = []
for _ in range(x):
    saida.append(random.randint(0, 100))
print saida # [74, 12, 15, 32, 74]
```

Nota que podes usar uma compreensão de lista para qualquer uma das soluções acima:

```
import random

x = 5
saida = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(x)]
print saida # [88, 37, 17, 27, 58]
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/Zmog0c) dos três exemplos acima

Comment: Dei uma vacilada e você foi mais rápido :p Boa resposta +1

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: De nada @Danilo

Answer (score 3):

É simples. Seria legal dar uma olhada no [módulo `random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html), lá tem várias formas de trabalhar com números aleatórios.

`randint` retorna um número inteiro entre os dois que foram passados por parâmetro.

```
from random import randint

x = int(raw_input('entre com o valor desejado: '))
vec = []

for i in range (x):
    vec.append(randint(0, 100))

print(vec)
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/HWKr/1)

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Me ajudou muito.